# how to catch a data from a array in WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

[image]

I got page information. but now I can't print specific data from this array.

```
$page_details = get_pages( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'meta_value' => 'template-parts/about.php'
   ));
   echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($page_details);// check the array value
    echo '</pre>';
var_dump($page_details["post_title"]);// it's return null value. this way I am trying catch the specific value. but it is wrong
```

I was known but recently I forget it. so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "array" you show in your screenshot is an array of [`WP_Post` objects](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) (well, in this case it's an array of 1 `WP_Post`).

In this specific case, you can get the page's information like this:

```
var_dump( $page_details[0]->post_title );
```

...which will get the `post_title` property from the zeroth (first) (well, only) `WP_Post` object in your array.

In the case where you've got more than one `WP_Post` in the array, you can get all their titles like this:

```
foreach ( $page_details as $page ) {
    var_dump( $page->post_title );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've wrong understood your question, but I supposed you want to change and output the title of a page. If yes, you can use the function the_title(), or if you need to change the value of the title you can use a filter the_title. Similarly, you can use a function the_content() and eponymous hook.